# What does it mean for a promotion in SFCC to be active?

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2c

What does it mean for a promotion in SFCC to be active?

In the documentation section over [here](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/Promotions/APIsForGetPromotionProducts.html?cp=0_3_3_7_8_4) (Salesforce B2C Commerce 19.9 > Merchandising Your Site > Campaigns and Promotions > Promotions for Developers > APIs for Promotions > APIs for Get Promotion Products) it is said the following:

> B2C Commerce considers a product promotion to be searchable if its Searchable flag is set to True and if it's active at any time 20 days in the past, any time 20 days in the future, or is currently active in the context of a campaign or A/B test.

I believe that it will become clear what it means for a promotion to be active if someone will tell me how I can check in BM how long ago a promotion was active.

Comment: In this case, you might need to set a custom attribute in the promotion that will save the date on which the promotion became inactive. And a code that saves the date (or maybe a timestamp would be better) in that attribute based on the conditions that makes the promotion inactive.

Comment: This is possible, but I dont think that there is any straight method to do it, or the existing BM functionality.